# How to reverse lookup in SPARQL query?

Tags: sparql, jena, fuseki

I'm trying to create a SPARQL query to return all the [Land Registry](https://landregistry.data.gov.uk/app/qonsole) House Price Index data for a region by searching for the name. I am stuck on one part of this, which I have set out below.

This code returns up the Region Name, based on the Region Identifier. This works and returns "Barnet".

```
prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>


SELECT 
 ?region ?regionName
WHERE
{
  <http://landregistry.data.gov.uk/id/region/barnet>  rdfs:label ?regionName .
}
```

However, I would like to reverse this so I can get the Region Identifier by entering the Region Name. The below code result is  "No Data in Table". I've spent a good few hours looking at tutorials and think it should be working based on what they say. Am I missing something obvious?

```
prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

SELECT 
 ?region 

WHERE
{
  ?region  rdfs:label "Barnet" .
}
```

Comment: `"Barnet"@en`. View results of your first query as plain text.

Comment: True. But to be fair, it's hard to see given that in most of the web interfaces the language tag isn't shown up but the lexical form of a string literal is just shown. Same holds for this https://landregistry.data.gov.uk/app/qonsole, So, yes, click on "Table" to choose a different format instead of this TSV based table. What often also works is to use a DESCRIBE query, like `
DESCRIBE <http://landregistry.data.gov.uk/id/region/barnet>`

Comment: Thanks, I was missing something! Really helpful. I would mark as question answered but can't see the button for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, if you click to view the data as plain text then you can see that there is also a language tag on the data. The tag needs to be included when searching, otherwise the match won't be made.